# Spark: where doesn't work properly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have 2 dataset, and i want to create a join dataset, so I did

```
Dataset<Row> join = ds1.join(ds2, "id");
```

However for performance enhancement I tried to replace join with `.where(cond)` ( I also tried `.filter(cond`) ) like this:

```
Dataset<Row> join = ds1.where(col("id").equalTo(ds2.col("id"));
```

which also work, but not when one of the datasets is empty ( In this case it will return the non-empty dataset), However this is not the expected result.

So my question why `.where` doesn't work properly in that case, or is there another optimized solution for joining 2 datasets without using `join()`.

Comment: Why do you think `where` is a performance enhancement over `join`?

Comment: @pault I heard it from an expert, also I tried to measure time of execution of filter and join, and filter seems to be faster, maybe because join use Cartesian product for joining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join and where condition are 2 different things. Your code for where condition will fail due to the resolve attribute issue. The where condition or filter condition is specific to that DataFrame. If you will mention second DataFrame in the condition it won’t iterate over like join. Please check your code if you are getting the result at all

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely one of the key points when you want to join two RDDs, is the partitioner used over those two. If the first and the second rdd has the same partitioner then your join operation would be in the best performance it could be. If paritioner varies, then the first rdd's partitioner would be used to partition the second rdd.

Then try to just use a "light key", e.g. use encoded or hashed output of a String instead using the raw, and the same partitioner for both the rdds.